# For Install MacOS mojave

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave

I purchased a MacBook Pro 6,2 (15" mid 2010) running macOS High Sierra

How I can install macOS Mojave in this Mac?

Several time I tried to install Mojave in this Mac, but it gives an error message that version is not compatible with this Mac.

Would you please help for solve my problem?

Comment: It's not compatible with your Mac.  See:  https://support.apple.com/kb/SP777?locale=en_US

Answer (score 1):

Several older model macs are not compatible with Mojave. [This site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201475) will list what Macs can run Mojave.  The only 2010 model listed is for an Mac Pro with a specific graphics card.

Comment: A 2010 iPad Pro that compatible with Mojave?  I must have missed that product announcement.

Comment: Only with a  recommended Metal-capable graphics card.

Comment: I'm trying to decide which temporal paradox would actually make that possible......

Comment: Several of them...

Comment: I  wish you had just said I made a typo!  but is was pretty humorouse!  lol

Comment: Sorry, but I just had to.... :-)

Comment: No problem. After seeing my mistake I thought it was funny!